# Agrupar elementos de um array durante um loop no php

Tags: php, array, loop, mpdf

Boa noite pessoal, venho com mais uma dúvida em um loop no php.

Estou precisando criar um PDF de um relatório bem extenso. Uma alternativa que o próprio MPDF indica, é criar blocos e ir escrevendo as páginas uma a uma. Vai ser uma sobrecarga mas, preciso gerar um pdf, com um relatório que pode ter até 100 mil registros (pretendo exibir 100 por página ou ir adaptando), por isso o MPDF não consegue receber o html todo de uma vez.

A questão é que estou com um array, onde cada índice recebe uma linha de dados (uma tag `<tr>`) que recebo do banco de dados. Porém eu queria agrupar isso em blocos de 100 por exemplo, ou seja, cada índice, agrupar 100 linhas.

O meu array atual segue esse formato

```
$tr = [
  0 => "<p>Valor 1</p>",
  1 => "<p>Valor 2</p>",
  2 => "<p>Valor 3</p>",
  3 => "<p>Valor 4</p>",
  4 => "<p>Valor 5</p>",
  ...
];
```

No exemplo acima, se fosse por exemplo 2 elementos por índice, eu precisaria que ficasse assim:

```
$tr = [
  0 => "<p>Valor 1</p> <p>Valor 2</p>",
  1 => "<p>Valor 3</p> <p>Valor 4</p>",
  2 => "<p>Valor 5</p>" ... 
];
```

Eu tentei fazer um loop, que mais parece uma gambiarra, mas dá alguns erros de índice e acaba perdendo alguns elementos, o que tentei foi isso:

```
$group = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= count($tr); $i++) {       
    for($i2 = 0; $i2 < 100; $i2++) {
        $group[$i] .= $tr[$i2];
        unset($tr[$i2]);
    }
    $tr = array_values($tr);
}
```

O que tentei fazer é, a cada laço do loop, preencher até os 100, e a laço do segundo for eu faço um unset limpando aquela variável, pra quando sair do for e ir pro próximo loop de fora, reorganizar o array sem os itens que já foram contabilizados.

Alguém consegue me ajudar com essa lógica. Não estou conseguindo pensar em uma maneira limpa e formar isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php) para quebrar sue array em blocos de 100 elementos. A cada um desses blocos você pode agrupar seus elementos usando a função [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) que junta elementos de um array em uma string.

No exemplo criei um array `$tr` contendo 731 elementos `<p>` e apliquei o raciocínio descrito acima.

```
<?php
//Cria um array com 731 elementos para o exemplo.
for($i=1;$i<=731;$i++){
  $tr[]="<p>Valor $i</p>";
}

//Quebra o array em blocos de 100 elementos e itera sobre eles.
foreach(array_chunk($tr, 100) as $item){
  $resultado[]= implode($item); //Agrupa cada bloco em uma string e a adiciona ao resultado.
}

print_r($resultado);
```

Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/AgruparElementos)